# Django formset without modelform not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create my first django formset. I'm following [this example](https://gist.github.com/ibarovic/3092910), but can't create a formset with only one model(other form is regular, no model attached).

> forms.py (relevant part)

```
class ArrivalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ['passenger_name', 'passenger_lastname', 'passenger_email', 'author_chain' ]

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
    helper.field_class = 'col-lg-9'

class RouteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        super(RouteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    place = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = forms.TimeField()

RouteInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(ArrivalForm, form=RouteForm, extra=2, can_delete=True)
```

> Error

```
TypeError at /reservations/create/arrival
inlineformset_factory() takes at least 2 arguments (4 given)
```

> Question

How can I create new formset for a `non-model` form. In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) I was only able to find how to do this for `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`formset_factory` is the one you need to create a formset without a model. You can read the details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view). Here is the example.

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.forms import ArticleForm, BookForm

def manage_articles(request):
    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)
    BookFormSet = formset_factory(BookForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='articles')
        book_formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='books')
        if article_formset.is_valid() and book_formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the cleaned_data on the formsets.
            pass
    else:
        article_formset = ArticleFormSet(prefix='articles')
        book_formset = BookFormSet(prefix='books')
    return render(request, 'manage_articles.html', {
        'article_formset': article_formset,
        'book_formset': book_formset,
    })
```